# Find minimum value of x in the equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Given equation : $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor {x/{5^i}} \rfloor \ge N$.

Here N is an integer whose value is known ( $1 \le N \le 10^9$), then how to find the minimum value of $x$ which satisfies the equation. Is there any direct formula for $x$ or we have to find the $x$ by hit and trial method between a certain range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct formula, but we can find a small range within which we need to search for $x$.

Let $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{x}{5^i} \right\rfloor$.

On the one hand, floors only round down, so we have
$$f(x) < \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x}{5^i} = \frac x4.$$
On the other hand, for $i > \log_5 x$, $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{5^i} \right\rfloor = 0$, and for smaller $i$, $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{5^i} \right\rfloor > \frac{x}{5^i} - 1$. So we have
$$
   f(x) \ge \sum_{i=1}^{\log_5 x} \left(\frac{x}{5^i} - 1\right) = \frac x4 - \frac{x}{4 \cdot 5^{\lfloor \log_5 x\rfloor}} - \lfloor \log_5 x\rfloor \ge \frac{x-1}{4} - \log_5 x.
$$
So we know that $\frac{x-1}{4} - \log_5 x \le f(x) < \frac x4$.

For the inverse problem, if $f(x) = N$, then we know $x > 4N$ from one bound, and $N \ge \frac{x-1}{4} - \log_5 x > \frac{x-1}{4} - \log_5 4N$ from the other bound, which translates to $x  < 4N + 1 + 4 \log_5 4N$.

So we only need to check the values of $x$ between $4N+1$ and $4N+1 + \lfloor 4 \log_5 4N\rfloor$.

Only integer values need to be checked: we have $f(x) = f(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ for all non-integer $x$.